# difference between receiving a reference or a Ptr in a callback

Tags: roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

assume 2 callbacks:

```
void cb1(const MsgType &);
void cb2(const MsgType::ConstPtr &);
```

In the case of cb2, each time a message is received a new object is created, i.e. memory allocation occurs. Well unless it's a nodelet, in which case the memory was allocated by the sender... but I'm not talking about that...

What about cb1? Is it the same object each time, i.e. memory does not need to be allocated if the message is the same size? That could save some time when dealing with large messages...

EDIT:
Since nobody understood my question, I'll try to reformulate. Actually I'd love to look at the actual code that does the deserialization and calls the callback function. Can somebody points it to me?

Here is 2 possible implementations of the message queue. This is pseudo code... but which concept is closer to the actual implementation?

```
// implementation that does not allocate the memory for each new message
class MessageQueue {
    queue<MsgType::SerializedType> serialized_msgs_;
    MsgType deserialized_msg_; //this object is allocated only once and reused

    void process() {
        deserialized_msg_.deserialize(serialized_msgs_.front());
        serialized_msgs_.pop();
        notify_callback( deserialized_msg_ ); //pass by const reference
    }
};

// another implementation that allocates new memory each time
class MessageQueue {
    queue<MsgType::SerializedType> serialized_msgs_;

    void process() {
        // allocate a new object each time
        MsgTypePtr deserialized_msg(new MsgType);
        deserialized_msg->deserialize(serialized_msgs_.front());
        serialized_msgs_.pop();
        notify_callback(deserialized_msg);
    }
};
```

In the first implementation, if we are dealing with a message that is always the same size, then no allocation is required at all which makes the code super efficient.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/81241/difference-between-receiving-a-reference-or-a-ptr-in-a-callback/) by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1001 on 2013-09-19

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2013-09-19**:
As far as I understood, both of them don't require coping. In other words, the first callback with reference creates just an alias(no memory allocation involved) and the other one creates a const pointer(no memory allocation involved as well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`MsgType::ConstPtr` is a typedef to a `boost::shared_ptr<const MsgType>`. What you win with a `MsgType::ConstPtr` is that you can store it and control its lifecycle, eg. for use outside the callback without incurring an extra copy.

With a plain `const MsgType&` the message data will go out of scope with the callback, and you'll have to make a copy to access the data from outside the callback.

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2013-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A reference does not make a copy, it is only guaranteed to be in scope for the duration of the callback.

The ConstPtr is a [Boost Shared Pointer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) which will reference count the underlying data, and copies of the pointer can be persisted and will keep the data in scope for longer.

I suggest getting more information from pure C++ forums such as Stack Overflow.  There are [lots](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417481/pointers-smart-pointers-or-shared-pointers) of [valuable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12119637/smart-pointers-vs-reference) reading [threads](http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/ref.html) This is a little off topic for ROS Answers.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-09-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I made a test, the result seems no performance difference.
I wonder whether I missed something.

test
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mdaTjM1VkkQ&feature=youtu.be
code
https://github.com/YuehChuan/ros-call-by-reference-test

---

Originally posted by [YuehChuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/54307/yuehchuan/) with karma: 11 on 2020-05-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1